# Three way partitioning of an array

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a three way partitioning of an given array using python.

My take:

```
def partition3(alist, lower, heigher, size):
    start = 0
    end = size-1
    for i in range(size):
        if alist[i] < lower:
            alist[i], alist[start] = alist[start], alist[i]
            start = start+1
        elif alist[i] > heigher:
            alist[i], alist[end] = alist[end],alist[i]
            end = end - 1
        else:
            pass
    return alist

def sort(alist, low, high):
    return partition3(alist, low, high, len(alist))

print sort([1, 14, 5, 20, 4, 2, 54, 20, 87, 98, 3, 1, 32], 10, 20)
```

The expected results should be,
1) All elements smaller than lowRange come first.
2) All elements in range lowVal to highRange come next.
3) All elements greater than highRange appear in the end.

This has to be done in an same array, shouldnt have three arrays.

Input:
List, lowRange and highRange.
but i am getting,

```
[1, 5, 4, 2, 14, 20, 32, 54, 87, 98, 3, 1, 20]
```

Need help on the things which i am missing here. Thanks in advance

Comment: How is that different from sorted list? Do you expect to have also lowRange > highRange?

Comment: If you want to partition, is it not easier to have 3 lists ?

Comment: Try to add in some print statements to see what happens.

Comment: @MateuszKorycinski I just want to do partitioning here and no sorting. It just has to satisfy those mentioned conditions.

Comment: @PinkFluffyUnicorn I want to use the same array for partitioning.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could do something like that (not optimal, most certainly there is a better way):

```
from itertools import chain
def sort_list_ranges(input_list, low, high):

    sorted_list = [[] for _ in range(3)]

    for elem in input_list:
        if elem < low:
           sorted_list[0].append(elem)
        elif elem > high:
           sorted_list[2].append(elem)
        else:
           sorted_list[1].append(elem)

    print [item for sublist in sorted_list for item in sublist]
```

It will give you a list containing values lower than 'low', middle range, and values higher than 'high'.

Comment: `sorted_list = [[],[],[]]` could be `sorted_list = [[] for _ in range(3)]`

Comment: True, that's more pythonic. Thanks!

Comment: and you'd have to chain the lists together to flatten them.

Comment: Thanks @Mate, but have to use the same array to do this. Shouldn't be using multiple arrays. Sorry i forgot to mention that in my question.

Comment: Also could be `[[]]*3`, probably the shortest option :)

Comment: @Akan Does it have to be operation on same list or can I create a single new list?

Comment: @MateuszKorycinski It has to be on the same list, shouldnt create another list.

Comment: @Phlya: no 3 times no. That would create the same reference for all 3 lists! Ok for immutable objects but NOT HERE

Comment: To keep original list just assign back using slice: `inputlist[:] = ...`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I forgot about that, you are right!

Answer (score 1):

```
def partition3(alist, lower, heigher):    
    n = len(alist)
    i, j, k = 0, 0, n
    while j < k:
        if alist[j] < lower:
            alist[i], alist[j] = alist[j], alist[i]
            i += 1
            j += 1
        elif alist[j] > heigher:
            k -= 1
            alist[j], alist[k] = alist[k], alist[j]                        
        else:
            j += 1
    

def sort(alist, low, high):
    partition3(alist, low, high)
    
a = [1, 14, 5, 25, 4, 2, 54, 17,  19, 87, 98, 3, 1, 32]
sort(a, 10, 20)
print(a)
a = [100, 99, 0, 1]
sort(a, 10, 20)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something based on your code:

```
def partition3(alist, lower, heigher, size):
    start = 0
    while alist[start] < lower:
        start = start + 1
    end = size-1
    while alist[end] > heigher:
       end = end - 1
    i = start
    while i <= end:
        if (i > start) and (alist[i] < lower):
            alist[i], alist[start] = alist[start], alist[i]
            while alist[start] < lower:
                start = start + 1
        elif alist[i] > heigher:
            alist[i], alist[end] = alist[end], alist[i]
            while alist[end] > heigher:
                end = end - 1
        else:
            i += 1
    return alist

def sort(alist, low, high):
    return partition3(alist, low, high, len(alist))

print sort([1, 14, 5, 20, 4, 2, 54, 20, 87, 98, 3, 1, 32], 10, 20)
```

It works on your example but I'm not 100% sure it's correct.

I think problems with your original version were

- what if start points to an element that is already smaller or end points to an element that is already larger? then the swap doesn't fix anything and the misorder may survive
- what if i runs past end? it will swap back all the correct upper third elements

Answer (score 0):

This is also working on your example, but maybe not the best solution.

```
    def partition3(alist, lower, heigher, size):
        start = 0
        end = size-1
        i=0
        while i < size-1:
            if alist[i] < lower:
                alist[i], alist[start] = alist[start], alist[i]
                start = start+1
                i=i+1
            elif alist[i] > heigher:
                if end < i+1:
                    break
                alist[i], alist[end] = alist[end],alist[i]
                end = end - 1
            else:
                i=i+1
        return alist

    def sort(alist, low, high):
        return partition3(alist, low, high, len(alist))

    print sort([1, 14, 5, 20, 4, 2, 54, 20, 87, 98, 3, 1, 32], 10, 20)
```

Output:
        [1, 5, 4, 2, 1, 3, 14, 20, 20, 98, 87, 32, 54]

Thanks @PaulPanzer the if statement for end < i+1 has to be first

Comment: Try `sort ([100, 99, 0, 1], 10, 20)` ;-)